# Unable to rewrite URL using Apache mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On the home page of my website, I have a guide that includes some links, and each redirects to a family guide page, all with the redirection by identification of each element of the guide, remaining as the link

```
https://example.com/family-guide/?id=4
```

Where '4' is the ID of the element.

I would like to leave like this:

```
https://example.com/family-guide/4
```

I tried to use mod_rewrite in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^family-guide/([0-9] +)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) family-guide/?Id=$1name=$2 [NC, L]
```

but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Your rule has some spaces. Be careful because if there is a space between the flags `[NC, L]` the rule is not valid.

Another thing is that you want the url `https://example.com/family-guide/4` to match a rule and your rule expects two parameters (id and name) while in this url there is only one.

I would use a couple of rules instead:

```
RewriteRule family-guide/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) family-guide/?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule family-guide/([0-9]+) family-guide/?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

With this rules if you go to `https://example.com/family-guide/4` you should be shown the content of `https://example.com/family-guide/?id=4`. And if you go to `https://example.com/family-guide/4/whatever` it will show you the content of `https://example.com/family-guide/?id=4&name=whatever` instead, which is what I understood you need.

Also, the rule order is important as if they were in the opposite order `https://example.com/family-guide/4/whatever` would match the other rule and show the content of `https://example.com/family-guide/?id=4/whatever`